# How to get ID of a query asked long ago and post it to another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in data base with columns like ID,question,date. and an php page (1.php)which outputs question and date from db table and takes answer in textarea. when clicked submit, it redirects to another php page (2.php) where i m supposed to store the typed answer into another table in db.

here, my problem is how can i add question_ID to the second table in db along with answer.

1.PHP script as follows::

```
<div class="name">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM input";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
 $index = 0;
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $index++;
?>

<div id="q">
<?php echo $row["question"]; ?> </B>
<?php
echo '<button class="add" id="add_'.$index.'"><B>Add Answer</B></button>';




                            echo '<form style="display:none;" name="answer_'.$index.'" method="post" action="output.php">'; // I dont think openning form from row to row would be nice!
                            echo '<textarea  type="text" class="addtext" name="addtext" required id="addtext_'.$index.'" placeholder="Please type your answer here.."  ></textarea>';
                            echo '<button onClick="addsubmit('.$index.');" type="submit" id="addsubmit_'.$index.'" class="addsubmit"><B>Submit</B></button>';
                            echo '</form>';
                        ?>
        <small><p><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></p></small>
```

2.PHP script as follows::

```
<?php include('1.php'); ?>
<?php
$servername  = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "******";
$dbname = "the_database";
$addtext = $_POST['addtext'];
$date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
$date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO output (answer, date)
VALUES ('$addtext', '$date')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo '<script language="javascript">';
 echo 'alert("Your Answer has been Succesfully posted")';
 echo '</script>';
 echo '<a href="answer.php"></a>';
}
else {
 echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer and date saved in db table successfully but got stuck in getting question_ID...

Any help is greatly Appreciated.

Comment: please format your code

Comment: what should i include?

Comment: what I said was to format your code not to include anything else

Comment: Like starting it with <htnl > and ending it with </html>..?

Comment: `=== TRUE` is total overkill here. The result will evaluate as logically false on a failure.

Comment: Once you've got this working, switch to prepared statements with bound parameters

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Add the hidden field:

on 1.php

```
echo '<form style="display:none;" name="answer_'.$index.'" method="post" action="output.php">'; // I dont think openning form from row to row would be nice!

echo '<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="<?php echo $row[ID]?>"/>'

echo '<textarea  type="text" class="addtext" name="addtext" required id="addtext_'.$index.'" placeholder="Please type your answer here.."  ></textarea>';

echo '<button onClick="addsubmit('.$index.');" type="submit" id="addsubmit_'.$index.'" class="addsubmit"><B>Submit</B></button>';

echo '</form>';
```

on page 2.php

```
$qid = $_POST['questionid']; //get the question id and insert in the table
```

Comment: i did exactly what you told man.. but still it is showing '0' in the question_id column...i double checked everything.. when i executed it, the output page didn't warned me anything regarding "undefined term questionid" like that, that means, php 2 is working well .. but php 1 script is not getting the id value i guess.....

Comment: Please check if you are getting correct questionid in loop

Comment: i m sorry which loop you are asking about

Comment: while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

Comment: yes... i checked it... in my first table the column name is just "id"  `echo '<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="<?php echo $row[id]?>"/>';`