# POSTING an ID from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in db, input table nd output table. input table got two columns `$ID (autoincreament), $question`. table 2 got two columns `$Q_ID, Answer`.

i made a php page (1) where i printed out the table 1 content (QUESTION) and i added a text area to get answers from visitors, along with it i also added a echo "hidden" field for ID from table one.

Now this php page 1 redirects to php page 2, where i POST the text area input into the answer column  in table 2. But unfortunately, the ID is not able to get posted in q_id column of table 2... 
I tried a lot but no hope..

**My PHP script #1 as follows**::

```
<div class="name">
    <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM input";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
        $index = 0; 
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
            $index++; // stuff inside foreach goes here 
            ?>

            <div id="q">
                <B><big><font color= #ba4a00> Q:</font></big> <?php echo $row["question"]; ?> 

                <?php 
                echo '<button class="add" id="add_'.$index.'"><B>Add Answer</B></button>';
                echo '<form style="display:none;" name="answer_'.$index.'" method="post" action="output.php">'; 
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="<?php echo $row[id]?>"/>';
                echo '<textarea  type="text" class="addtext" name="addtext" required id="addtext_'.$index.'" placeholder="Please type your answer here.."  ></textarea>';
                echo '<button onClick="addsubmit('.$index.');" type="submit" id="addsubmit_'.$index.'" class="addsubmit"><B>Submit</B></button>';
                echo '</form>';
                ?>
            </div>
        <?php     
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
    ?>
</div>
```

**My PHP script #2 as follows**::

```
<?php include('1.php'); ?>
<?php
    $servername  = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "*******";
    $dbname = "the_database";
    $addtext = $_POST['addtext'];
    $questionid = $_POST['questionid'];
    $date = date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
    $date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
    $conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "INSERT INTO output (question_id, answer, date)
    VALUES ('$questionid', '$addtext', '$date')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo '<script language="javascript">';
    echo 'alert("Your Answer has been Succesfully posted")';
    echo '</script>';
    echo '<a href="1.php"></a>';
    }
    else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
 ?>
```

i want the respective question id to be passed to table 2 along with its answer.
Any help is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ID of a query asked long ago and post it to another table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313745/how-to-get-id-of-a-query-asked-long-ago-and-post-it-to-another-table)

Comment: @e4c5 can you help me on this mate

Comment: @user6779766. have explained your Errors and answered your Question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give single-quote in `$row['id']`. Change this `<?php echo $row[id] >?` to `<?php echo $row['id'] >?`

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="'. $row['id'].'"/>';
```

Comment: it gave me some error like this... `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'id' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\the_database\answer.php on line 834`

Comment: Can you take a look at this one mate..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330887/slide-up-slide-down-is-not-working-for-selected-table-rows-from-db?noredirect=1#comment65993670_39330887

Answer (score 0):

try enclosing id in double quotes in php 1:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="'.$row['id'].'"/>';
```

yip... looking a this a bit more closely you've got a bit of a problem with mixing single and double quotes in PHP #1.

for example, on this line the echo command ends after the second single quote after add_

```
echo '<button class="add" id="add_'.$index.'"><B>Add Answer</B></button>';
```

You need to use either single or double quotes consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Already you are echoing the form using the ECHO Attribute in the PHP but after that also you have echoed it and that is wrong.

You have to make the code like this.

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="questionid" value="'. $row['id'].'"/>';
```

Try this and share the thought about the code..

Comment: If you already using echo you have to just concatenate the PHP code in the codes rather than echoing double time inside it. :)

Comment: After that you have the made the following errors. Already you have opened the PHP tag and echoing the data but again inside to you are reopening the PHP tag without closing it. hence it will lead to Error. So you have to remove that PHP tag and concatenate it in the ECHO statement.